# Arrays : Foreach

Tags: perl

I have the following :

```
my $v = "value";
my $v1 = "value";
my @v2 = ("v3", v4");
```

How can I have a foreach that will contain, v, v1 and elements of v2?something like :

```
foreach my $element ($v, $v1, @v2) {
 # Do something with the element. 
}
```

Essentially i want it to be the equivalent of

```
foreach my $element ($v, $v1, $v3, $v4) {

}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? When I execute `perl -e '@v = (4,5,6); foreach my $i(1,2,3,@v){printf("%d ", $i)}'` I get `1 2 3 4 5 6` as my output, as expected.

Comment: There's no `$v3` or `$v4` anywhere in that code. Do you mean `$v2[0]` and `$v2[1]`?

Comment: @ikegami, I think he meant "v3" and "v4" - since the values of array v2 aren't fully quote escaped, implying that the elements of array v2 are simply: ("v3", "v4"). That's how I took it - but, I could be wrong.

Comment: @jrd, I'm pretty sure he means the elements of `@v2`, not `"v3"` and `"v4"`.

Comment: @ikegami, correct - as per the definition of v2 in the first code sample - which contains "v3" and "v4".

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach my $element ($v, $v1, @v2) { ... }
```

is equivalent to

```
foreach my $element ($v, $v1, $v2[0], $v2[1], ..., $v2[$#v2]) { ... }
```

which seems to be exactly what you want it do.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, however - if you meant: **I have a foreach that will contain, v, v1 and elements of v2**, then this is what you would do (in your notation):

```
my $v = "value1";
my $v1 = "value2";
my @v2 = ("v3", "v4");

foreach my $element($v, $v1, @v2) {
    print $element . "\n";
}
```

This will give you the output:

```
value1
value2
v3
v4
```

How does this work? **The foreach loop iterates over a list of values by setting the control variable (VAR) to each successive element of a list:**

```
foreach VAR (LIST) {
    ...
}
```

In your case, the control variable name is **$element**, and the list and its values are: **($v, $v1, @v2)** - or, *more explicitly*: **("value1", "value2", "@v2[0]", "@v2[1]") - which can be thought of as - (but, not really) the following: ("value1", "value2", "v3", "v4")**.

And, as per ikegami's warning, FYI: **if you modify the $element value in the loop, the values held in the list will in turn, be modified.**

Comment: Not quite the same as `for my $element ("value1", "value2", "v3", "v4")`. Consider what happens when you change the value of `$element`.

Comment: @ikegami, agreed - however, if he wants to modify the values, then that's another answer, IMO.

Comment: I wasn't warning of anything. I was just saying the two things you claimed are equivalent aren't quite.

Comment: @ikegami, okay. Is this regarding `for my $element ...` vs `foreach my $element ..`? If so, then they are equivalent as per the [perl-docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops). If not, to what are you referring?

Comment: `$v, $v1, @v2` vs `"value1", "value2", "v3", "v4"`

Comment: Agreed again, I was simply elaborating what was actually happening. To be truly explicit, that would be `@v2[0]`, and `@v2[1]`, which in turn are `"v3"` and `"v4"` respectively. What I quoted can be considered "can be thought of as such". I've edited it for clarity. You're right though. Sorry for the confusion.